# What does the ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x]/I$ look like, where $I = $\langle x(x-1) \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Maybe it's a stupid question but what does the ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x]/I$ look like? Here, $I$ is the ideal $\langle x(x-1) \rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Everything helping!

Thanks :)

Comment: You should specify what $C$ and $I$ is.

Comment: This is highly dependent upon what $C$ and $I$ are.

Comment: Well C[x] is the set of polynomials in x with coefficients in C (complex numbers) and I is the ideal in C[x] :)

Comment: $\Bbb{C}[x]$ has infinitely many ideals. What is $I$?

Comment: I is generated by x(x-1)

Answer (score 5):

A proper and nonzero ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is generated by a single non constant monic polynomial $f$. Decompose $f$ as
$$
f(x)=(x-a_1)^{m_1}(x-a_2)^{m_2}\dots(x-a_k)^{m_k}
$$
with $a_1,\dots,a_k$ pairwise distinct and $m_i>0$ (for $i=1,2,\dots,k$). Then the Chinese remainder theorem applies and
$$
\mathbb{C}[x]/I\cong
\mathbb{C}[x]/((x-a_1)^{m_1})\times
\mathbb{C}[x]/((x-a_2)^{m_2})\times
\dots\times
\mathbb{C}[x]/((x-a_k)^{m_k})
$$
where $((x-a_i)^{m_i})$ denotes the ideal generated by $(x-a_1)^{m_1}$.

Thus the problem reduces to study the quotients of the form
$$
\mathbb{C}[x]/((x-a)^{m})\cong\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^{m})
$$
which are quite easy: they are the polynomials of degree less than $m$, where multiplication is performed normally, but removing terms of degree $m$ or more. In particular, if $m=1$ the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.